# ruby: unknown encoding name: undecided

Tags: ruby, encoding, ruby-1.9

I've actually figured out what causes this error, but Googling for it was unsuccessful so I thought I'd write it down here to help out other people. This error pops up when you've got an `# -*- coding: undecided -*-` comment at the top of one of your files. Emacs added this automatically for me, but re-saving the file caused it to be changed to the correct `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`.

Comment: Anex3: the preferred format to to ask a question. If you have the answer, create a seperate answer.

Comment: @nex3 : Okay. So now write an answer to your post and accept it as the answer so this question disappears from the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 8):

This error pops up when you've got an `# -*- coding: undecided -*-` comment at the top of one of your files. Emacs added this automatically for me, but re-saving the file caused it to be changed to the correct `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`.